# Android application and capacitive display

Tags: android, screen

How Android application can receive raw data from capacitive display
e.g. coordinates and specific capacitance value measurement?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that android will give you a specific capacitive value measurement (i.e. X.X microFarads) - that is likely measured by the hardware and then read into the processor as a raw digital value.  Instead, Android provides you with "touch pressure" measurements in the `MotionEvent.PointerCoords` class, which is contained in the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) class.  Each touch event (or un-touch event, also) generates a `MotionEvent` data structure, and in the `MotionEvent.PointerCoords` class there is a `pressure` field.  This may be what you are looking for.

Each `View` on your screen (i.e. button, text field, etc) can receive a `MotionEvent`.  When it does, the view's `onTouchEvent()` callback method is invoked, and the second parameter in that method is the related `MotionEvent`.  Look in there as described above to find touch pressure.

If you really are looking for specific capacitance values, I don't think you'll find it - I can't imagine why they would expose that in the API.  However, if you research the hardware you may be able to figure out the conversion factors (i.e. a `MotionEvent.PointerCoords` `pressure` value of `X` corresponds to a capacitance value of `Y`), but I have no idea where you would find that information and I'm certain it varies from one mobile device to the next.